# Get API response from redux store and send response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What i want to execute is do a post request and access the res.json() and taking res.json() i want to dispatch a action  to update the store and access response object in the component.A small code example will be great.

```
export const filesDownload = (postData) => dispatch =>{
    console.log(postData);
    fetch('http://'+ip+':8000/api/v1/integrator/email/need_attachment/',{
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(postData)
    })
        .then(res => console.log(res.json()))
        .then(files => dispatch({
        type: GET_FILES,
        payload:files
    }))
}
```

I want to dispatch the res.json() to the store .

Comment: change this line `.then(res => console.log(res.json()))` to `.then( res => res.json())` you need to return the res inorder to get the files in the chained then.

Comment: ok done now  how do i get the response to the store

Comment: You have a reducer listening to the actions rite?

Comment: yes i do have a reducer listening

Comment: Your code will work, just need to remove ".then(res => console.log(res.json()))".

Comment: This solution also worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try axios its cleaner:

```
export const filesDownload = (postData) => dispatch =>{
  console.log(postData);
    axios.post('http://'+ip+':8000/api/v1/integrator/email/need_attachment/')
    .then((response)=>response.data)
    .then((files)=>dispatch({
    type: GET_FILES,
    payload:files
    }))
    .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
}
```

If it's not working, you will have to use redux Thunk, tell me, I will help you

Comment: in case maybe you should check console.log(ip) to be sure ip is defined

Comment: yeah that is defined i have just not posted it here

Comment: Nice ok, then it should work :) If your result is not shown in reducer, will need redux thunk